# How to read a dataframe by 2 lines in order to return a half len dataset

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with len 299357 lines and 7 columns.I want to count by 2 and create a new dataset

The code is the following:

```py
df.shape(299357, 7)

dff = []
for i in range(0, len(df),2):
    dff.append(i)

len(dff)
# >>> 147920

#then i convert the list to dataframe again with
dff= pd.DataFrame (dff)
```

But when I see `dff.shape` I get back `(147920, 1)`

Where are my 7 columns for df?

`df.head` is like this:

```
    activity    accx        accy        accz        gurx        gury        gurz
0   downstairs  -0.326721   0.858704    0.065735    10.666921   8.025915    19.824696
1   downstairs  -0.331909   0.867249    0.064453    10.659299   7.591464    19.862804
2   downstairs  -0.336182   0.871216    0.060364    11.036586   7.408537    20.865091
3   downstairs  -0.342529   0.875122    0.060974    11.303354   7.210366    22.012196
4   downstairs  -0.347900   0.878174    0.062927    11.238567   7.511433    22.648628
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it in a simple way.

```
new_df = df.iloc[::2, :]
```

The part before the comma inside the bracket (::2) selects all the rows while skipping 2, and the part after the comma (:) selects all the columns.